# Using pagespeed with phantomjs and jenkins integration

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, phantomjs, yslow

I am trying to automate web page performance using pagespeed.

Is there any plugin available for pagespeed to run on phantomjs

we have yslow plugin for the same and its working locally

http://yslow.org/phantomjs/

I am using the command line and then integrating the same with Jenkins for continous integration

thanks and appreciate your help

some sample code

```
 phantom.create (ph) ->
      ph.createPage (page) ->
        page.open "http://www.google.com", (status) ->
          console.log "opened google? ", status
          page.evaluate (-> document.title), (result) ->
            console.log 'Page title is ' + result
            ph.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PageSpeed is a C++ binary, you might want to try integrating PhantomJS `netsniff.coffee` (from the [examples](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netsniff.coffee)) that generates a HAR file of a given page piping the output into [HAR_to_PageSpeed](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/01/har-to-page-speed/). Or just go with [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) online service.